# Draw plot on a supercomputer using ipython

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, supercomputers

I want to plot a figure using python on a supercomputer.

For example, I wrote a script **plot.py**：

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
....
....
plt.plot(m) # m is a matrix with size (1000,36) 
plt.show()
```

If I do:

> python3 plot.py

there is no picture. But I can get all other numerical output. (I can get a figure with the same script on my mac with python3.6 but not at supercomputer)

But if I do:

> ipython -i  --matplotlib=tk -- plot.py 1 2 3 4

or

> ipython -i  --pylab=tk  -- plot.py 1 2 3 4

The plot will show up.

I tried to delete "-i", and it seemed that "-i" is necessary. I don't understand the logic behind it. Why can we not use python3 directly on a supercomputer to plot?  And why --matplotlib=tk or --pylab=tk  all worked but deleting both of them will not work. And "1 2 3 4" is not necessary.

Could someone help to explain why "ipython -i" works on a supercomputer?

Comment: What is a "supercomputer"? Is that some local marketing name for a Dell or something?

Comment: maybe its the `i` in front that does your magic, by providing a visual frontend for your supercomputer - its probably related to this: https://ipython.org/

Comment: @MadPhysicist “supercomputer” is the computer clusters we use @ McGill. Here is a link to it: http://www.hpc.mcgill.ca/

Comment: I suggest you contact your support.

Comment: Most likely you dont have X11 forwarding enabled, or your local cluster has a non graphical backend for matplotlib enabled. This isn’t really a programming question.